# Hide div for Radio button selected value using jquery- Not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to hide a div (AppliedCourse), when radi button value is Agent. I wrote below code but it is not working.
Any idea?

```
$('#HearAboutUs').click(function() {
    $("#AppliedCourse").toggle($('input[name=HearAboutUs]:checked').val()='Agent');
    });

 <tr><td class="text"><input type="radio" name="HearAboutUs" value="Press">Press & Print media
<input type="radio" name="HearAboutUs" value="Internet">Internet
<input type="radio" name="HearAboutUs" value="Agent">Agent
<input type="radio" name="HearAboutUs" value="Friend">Friend
<input type="radio" name="HearAboutUs" value="Other" checked="checked">Other</td></tr>
```

Comment: try == 'Agent', also where is your div?

Comment: `$('#HearAboutUs')` targets an element with the ID of `HearAboutUs`. I don't see one in your example. Fix that and the mistake that Quantico pointed out and it works http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/v6nnmtyx/

Comment: Also have you checked your console? I tried to copy your code to jsfiddle and there are a bunch of errors. As @j08691 said where is your id

Comment: Another option is `$("input[name='HearAboutUs']").click(function() {`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either your HTML is incomplete or your first selector is wrong. It is possible that your click handler is not being called because you have no element with id 'HeadAboutUs'. You might want to listen to clicks on the inputs themselves in that case.

Also, your logic is not quite right. Toggle hides the element if the parameter is false, so you want to negate it using !=. Try:

```
$('input[name=HearAboutUs]').click(function() {
    var inputValue = $('input[name=HearAboutUs]:checked').val()
    $("#AppliedCourse").toggle( inputValue!='Agent');
});
```

I have made a JSFiddle with a working solution: http://jsfiddle.net/c045fn2m/2/

Comment: I think you're missing quotes around `HearAboutUs`

Comment: Thanks @Dan but I they are not strictly required. "Attribute values must be identifiers or strings." From: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#attribute-selectors

Comment: +1 Interesting to learn that quoutes are not strictly required.

Answer (score 3):

Your code is looking for an element with id `HearAboutUs`, but you don't have this on your page.

You do have a bunch of inputs with `name="HearAboutUs"`.  If you look for those, you'll be able to execute your code.

```
$("input[name='HearAboutUs']").click(function() {
    var clicked = $(this).val(); //save value of the input that was clicked on
    if(clicked == 'Agent'){ //check if that val is "Agent"
        $('#AppliedCourse').hide();
    }else{
        $('#AppliedCourse').show();
    }
});
```

**[JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jcu8d9jv/1/)**

Another option as suggested by @Regent is to replace the if/else statement with `$('#AppliedCourse').toggle(clicked !== 'Agent');`.  This works too.

Comment: Why do you not want to use `.toggle()` instead of `if-else`?

Comment: @Regent yeah i saw your note on the other question - it's a good idea!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/L9bfddos/

```
<tr>
<td class="text">
     <input type="radio" name="HearAboutUs" value="Press">Press & Print media
     <input type="radio" name="HearAboutUs" value="Internet">Internet
     <input type="radio" name="HearAboutUs" value="Agent">Agent
     <input type="radio" name="HearAboutUs" value="Friend">Friend
     <input type="radio" name="HearAboutUs" value="Other" checked="checked">Other
</td>
```

Test

```
$("input[name='HearAboutUs']").click(function() {
var value = $('input[name=HearAboutUs]:checked').val();
if(value === 'Agent'){
    $('#AppliedCourse').hide();
}
else{
    $('#AppliedCourse').show();
}
});
```

Comment: `$('#AppliedCourse').toggle(value !== 'Agent');` is much shorter than `if-else`, but works in the same way.

Comment: Yes, you are right, that's what happens when you try to answer a question as fast as possible.